# Android Packaging Error: semicolon expected

Tags: android, eclipse

When I package my app, it's gets to 35% complete, then the following error message shows up and it stops.
Any idea what it could be?  Thanks I appreciate it!

```
[ERROR] /Users/emes/Folder/Apps/MyApp/build/android/gen/com/*gameplay*/*mole*/ApplicationStylesheet.java:5: ';' expected
[ERROR] package com.gameplay.mole;
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/emes/Folder/Apps/MyApp/build/android/gen/com/*gameplay*/*mole*/moleActivity.java:1: ';' expected
[ERROR] package com.gameplay.mole;
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/emes/Folder/Apps/MyApp/build/android/gen/com/*gameplay*/*mole*/moleAppInfo.java:1: ';' expected
[ERROR] package com.gameplay.mole;
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/emes/Folder/Apps/MyApp/build/android/gen/com/*gameplay*/*mole*/moleApplication.java:6: ';' expected
[ERROR] package com.gameplay.mole;
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/emes/Folder/Apps/MyApp/build/android/gen/com/*gameplay*/*mole*/R.java:8: ';' expected
[ERROR] package com.gameplay.mole;
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] 5 errors
[INFO] Compiling Android Resources... This could take some time
[INFO] Installing application on device
[ERROR] Failed installing com.*gameplay*.mole: pkg: /data/local/tmp/app.apk
```

Comment: post your code, so that we can figure out what the problm is..?

Comment: Agree with @ntc, seems that you have compilation errors (a hunch tells me you have two classes inside one java file).